# Move files on a remote machine via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to move files on a remote machine from folder A to folder B via ssh.

I am using this command:
ssh user@server "sh scan/script.sh"

This will run a script which contains some file operations, moving files around on the remove machine. The problem is that my SSH seems to attempt to execute the contents of script.sh on my local computer.

I am using zsh.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Pass the `-v` flag to `ssh` to understand what is happenning

Comment: *"The problem is that my SSH seems to attempt to execute the contents of script.sh on my local computer."* Is it moving the files on the remote machine? Is it moving the files on the local computer? Why do you suspect the script is being executed on the wrong computer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can execute remote commands through ssh, for instance:

ssh  -n user@host mv fileOnRemoteServer destination

Answer (score 0):

You're on a Linux box? That should work without any problems.

Now, are you sure that the command isn't running on the remote machine, but merely displaying the output of the script on your machine? That would make it appear the script is running on your machine even though it isn't.

Comment: This was the case. Thanks!

Is there any way this can be avoided?

Comment: @Hendrik - When you log in with SSH, some systems set an environment variable of `SSH_CLIENT` or `SSH_CONNECTION`. I'm Kornshell, not BASH, so I can't verify this, but might be possible to set something up in `.bashrc` to print a warning if one of these environment variables are set. Doesn't work in Ksh because you set the name of the environment file in `.profile` and ssh doesn't execute that. Give it a try and let me know. Otherwise, you'll have to put something in your scripts itself.